# JQuery: wrapping variable's contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

I have a variable that contains a bunch of HTML that I retrieve from a HTML5 SQL database.

I can `.append()` this to an element in the DOM and it appears fine. But I want to `.wrap()` the HTML contents first, thus I have written:

```
content = $(content).wrap(function() {
                                     return '<div class="event_holder" />';
                                     });

$('#mydiv').append(content);
```

However, I get the error

`Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ~HTML contents of variable~`

I have also tried:

```
content = $(content).wrap('<div class="event_holder" />');
```

Would anyone know whats going on here and how I can correctly wrap this?

EDIT: the contents of 'content' is:

```
<input id="e1coords" class="coords" name="e1coords" type="hidden" value="-27.482359,153.024725">
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem could be `content = $(content).wrap('<div class="event_holder" />');` still returns the inner content not the wrapped element, you need to append the parent of the content.

Try

```
content = $(content).wrap('<div class="event_holder" />').parent();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SqHSa/)

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why are you using callback of `wrap()` when you can do it directly

```
content = $(content).wrap('<div class="event_holder" />');
```

and it will be better if you can show us what actually the `content` contents..

**updated**

try this

```
content = $('#e1coords').wrap('<div class="event_holder" />');
```

OR

```
var content = $('#e1coords');
content = content.wrap('<div class="event_holder" />');
```

Comment: Sorry - I should have mentioned, I tried that way as well. Just experimenting. I will adjust my question

Answer (score 0):

I found out the because the `content` variable was actually retrieved from a (html5) database it was not part of the DOM, thus JQuery was having issues with it.

I did the wrap manually and it worked

```
content = '<div class="event_holder">' + content + '</div>';
```